# Don't show gui after installation of Edge extension

Tags: windows-10-universal, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

After the installation of my uwp app through a package (i created a package but haven't published it to store yet) the installation window have a 'Launch' button, which launches GUI. But my app is an edge extension which uses background task and desktop bridge. I want the installation program to launch Edge instead.

I heard that the GUI window is a requirement to publish app to store.

Comment: Edge Extensions have their own Windows store category. see the documentation about publishing your Edge extension. developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/faq .... usually the publisher-url in the manifest would be launched when the extension is first installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to leave entry point in the manifest empty, and then after hitting the launch button after installation from windows store edge will be opened. That's information from  the guy from microsoft.